# Incompatible types: List CSVRecords java

Tags: java, list, apache-spark, rdd

I'm a beginner in `Spark-Java`, I want to get a subList from a List in `Java 8`. Then I convert it to an RDD. I did it in this code bellow:

```
            List<CSVRecord> inputRecords = readInputLayer(actorSystem, inputCatalog, inputCatalogVersion);
            LOGGER.info("Number of partition " +inputRecords.size());

            List<CSVRecord> inputRecordsTmp = inputRecords.stream().limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());


            JavaRDD<CSVRecord> inputRecordsJavaRDD = JavaSparkContext.emptyRDD();
            for (List<CSVRecord> partition: inputRecordsTmp ){
                JavaRDD<CSVRecord> inputRecordsTmpRDD = (JavaRDD<CSVRecord>) JavaSparkContext.parallelize(partition);
                inputRecordsJavaRDD = JavaSparkContext.union(inputRecordsJavaRDD,inputRecordsTmpRDD);

            }

        LOGGER.info("Number of lines to insert JAVA RDD =" +inputRecordsJavaRDD.count());
```

But I got an error in a loop for, 
it do not accept `List<CSVRecord> partition:`

```
Incompatible types:
Required: org.apache.commons.csvRecord
Found: java.util.list  <org.apache.commons.csvRecord>
```

How can I correct it ?
Thank you

Comment: Why use an RDD vs. a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Just had a look at the documentation. `parallelize` in fact accepts a List, but this only means that you do not need a foreach at all. You should be able to just pass your `inputRecordsTmp` right into parallelize and get your RDD out of it.

Still, since the foreach is formulated incorrectly, I'll leave this here for further information:

First of all, your for-each-loop does not look entierly correct to me. When writing a for-each-loop in Java, the part before the colon is supposed to be of the type of the element in the collection you're iterating over.

In your case, you have a List that contains CSVRecord objects. In a for-each you are basically saying "for each CSVRecord in this List of CSVRecord objects...". However, you have written "for each List of CSVRecord objects in this list of CSVRecord objects...", which doesn't make much sense.

Java already knows that `inputRecordsTmp` is a List of CSVRecords, so no need to specify that again anywhere. What you instead want to tell it is, that for each object in the list, you want to extract that object into a variable (`partition` in your case) so you can use that extracted object inside your loop.

So instead of writing

```
for (List<CSVRecord> partition: inputRecordsTmp ){
```

You would have to write

```
for (CSVRecord record: inputRecordsTmp ){
```

This *might* solve your problem. If not, could you please add information on what line exactly is failing?

Comment: Thank you for your naswer. 
The code failing in the loop line for (List<CSVRecord> partition){.

So you're right, I should use in a loop one record if in List CSVRecord.

This may solve the half of the problem, because when I do your solution I got another error n a parallelize(partition). So it's normaly because I'm trying to convert List to an RDD and partition is  not a List.

In my example above, I want just take 100 elements from a List<CSVRecord> loop it then I should return an RDD as I did in my example but I was an error in incompatibility of types.

Comment: @Dorine Thanks for your comment! Have you seen my edit about `parallelize`? As it accepts a `List`, as far as I can see, it should suffice if your just passed your List with the 100 records as argument. The for-loop should not be necessary.

Comment: I did like you described above, I just convert a list to an RDD using a function parallelize. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help!